# How to reference a specific version of an assembly from an F# script?

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

I have both XNA 3.1 and 4.0 installed on my system. I can choose a specific version when adding a reference to my F# project, but how do I do that in F# interactive or in an F# script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do that by specifying the exact path for the assembly:

```
#r @"C:\path to xna 3.1\library.dll"
```

Alternatively, you can use `#I @"C:\path to xna 3.1"` to include the path with specific version of assemblies and then just use `#r "assembly.dll"`.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing, but I was hopping I wouldn't have to use the full path, which might differ from one PC to another. It would be nice if all assembly files followed a naming convention similar to those of libraries on Linux, i.e libmylib.so linked to libmylib-1.so linked to libmylib-1.2.so... This would allow referring to specific versions using the filename by itself.